How to access advanced options window opened after clicking advanced button in indexing options using pywinauto?
I am not able to access advanced options window opened after clicking advanced button, I am not able to access the window or any control identifiers
from pywinauto import Application, findwindows, mouse , Desktop    
from pywinauto.timings import wait_until, TimeoutError
import time
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init 
import subprocess

# Opening indexing options

command = "control.exe srchadmin.dll"

subprocess.run(command, shell=True)

sleep(2)

#app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="Indexing Options", found_index=0)
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Indexing Options')

#access the child window advanced options opened thru click and open advanced options
indexing_options = app.window(title = 'Indexing Options')
#indexing_options.print_control_identifiers()
indexing_options.child_window(auto_id = '407').click()

try:
advanced_options_window = Desktop(backend="uia")\['Advanced Options'\]
wait_until(10, 1, lambda: advanced_options_window.exists())

    # Print all the elements in the 'Advanced Options' window
    advanced_options_window.print_control_identifiers()

except TimeoutError:
print("The 'Advanced Options' window did not appear.")

finally:
# Close the Indexing Options window
indexing_options.close()


The right path to "Advanced Options" looks so:
Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Indexing Options").child_window(title="Advanced Options").wait("exists")

It is visible in Inspect.exe that this is a child of "Indexing Options" window.
